# How do I force dependents on my INTERFACE library to use C++11 or later?

Tags: c++, cmake, build-definition, build-dependencies, header-only

I'm in the process of splitting a library of mine into a header-only lib and a compiled lib, so, for the first time, I'm trying to use CMake to "build", or rather expose, a header-only library.

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671383/benefits-of-header-only-libraries) and the CMake documentation, I understand I need to use an INTERFACE library, without sources. But - my headers must be compiled with a C++ language standard version of at least C++11. When I was actually compiling something, I made do with:

```
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

but that's:

1. Not exactly what I need for code using the header-only lib - I need to say "at least C++11".
2. Can't be used on INTERFACE libraries.

I noticed there is no `set_property(... INTERFACE)`. So how am I suppoed to force dependent code to use C++11-or-later?

**Edit:** I am interested both in answers for constraining an *exact* C++ version choice in dependents, and for constraining "at least" - in case the latter is problematic/difficult/impossible.

Comment: I searched a bit and I found [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148275/inducing-minimal-c-standard-version-in-cmake). Both answers are interesting. But it seems you don't have a clean way to specify the "at least".

Comment: I'd put it somewhere in the header file `static_assert(__cplusplus >= 201103L, "C++11 or later required");`

Comment: @TedLyngmo: That's useful, I suppose. But - I want a failure during the build configuration phase, not during compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a fairly recent version of cmake, you can try

```
target_compile_features(foo INTERFACE cxx_std_11)
```

This ensures that every library that uses foo, i.e.

```
target_link_libraries(bar PRIVATE foo)
```

will be compiled with C++11. For example if bar uses source file *bar.cpp*, then *bar.cpp* will be compiled with *std=c++11* by cmake.

Comment: "with C++11" - exactly, or at least?

Comment: well If you specify std=c++11 you get exactly c++11 so I would say exact :)

Comment: If you need some fine grained control of features. for example if you want constexpr support but do not want to fix things to c++11 or 17 you can use `target_compile_features(foo INTERFACE cxx_constexpr)`. CMake will make sure that it is supported and `bar` is compiled with that support.

Comment: Ok, just making sure. I know about the fine-grained control of features, maybe that's a good idea - since it's a bit like "at least C++11". But - do these cover all C++11 features, or just some?

Comment: ... Ah, wait: CMake documentation says that "cxx_std_11:  Compiler mode is at least C++ 11." !

Comment: Use the `target_*` commands instead of `set_property()` ones when you can. You can see the target_compile_features() here. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html